# How do I search a Document witht tf-idf and pairwise similarity?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, nltk

I am trying to build a search tool for text files based based on Tf-Idf and Pairwise similarity with pandas and sklearn.

The following code is what I have so far:

I have a text file or web page that I can scrape which will I am using to build my initial corpus. I then build a pandas dataframe and perform some prepocessing on the documents.

Afterwards I build train my TfidfVectorizer and build the matrix for my corpus.

Then I create a second dataframe with the Text I am searching, preprocess it and build a second matrix based on the earlier trained vectorizer.

At last I calculate my cosine similarity matrix.

```
texts = scrapper.getTexts([opts.url])  # module that scrapes a webpage
columns = ['section', 'title', 'paragraph']
df = pd.DataFrame(texts, columns=columns)
model = preprocess(df) #Remove stopwords, lemmatize etc.

corpus = df['lemmatized_sents'].tolist()
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=1, use_idf=True)
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(raw_documents=corpus)

to_search = pd.DataFrame({'paragraph': 
          ["Text i am search for in the orig. document"]})

to_search = preprocess(to_search)
to_search_matrix = vectorizer.transform(to_search['lemmatized_sents'].tolist())

cosine_similiarities = metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(
        to_search_matrix, matrix).flatten()
```

Now, what is not clear to me is, how I get back to my original corpus based on the cosine similarities. How do I find the entry in my original dataframe which is most similar to the searched text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cosine_similarities.argmax()
```

Will return the index of your document that has the biggest cosine similarity. Alternatively you can use something like `nlargest` from `heapq` to get *k* biggest values.

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for.
Do you have an example how to do it with heapq?

Comment: I don't, but I can give you a hint: use `heapq.nlargest`.